# if statement does not work and does not show echo's

Tags: php, html

```
 <?php
  $reg = @$_POST['reg'];
  $fn        =   "";
  $ln        =   "";
  $un        =   "";
  $em        =   ""; 
  $pswd      =   ""; 
  $d         =   "";
  $u_check   =   ""; 

  $fn   =   strip_tags(@$_POST['fname']);
  $ln   =   strip_tags(@$_POST['lname']);
  $un   =   strip_tags(@$_POST['uname']);
  $em   =   strip_tags(@$_POST['email']); 
  $pswd =   strip_tags(@$_POST[ 'pass']);  
  $d = date('Y-m-d');

  if ($reg) {
      echo 'test';
  }
 ?>
<div class="form">
    <input class="Firstname"  type="text"     name="fname"       placeholder="Fisrt name">
    <input class="Lastname"   type="text"     name="lname"       placeholder="Last name">
    <input class="username"   type="text"     name="uname"       placeholder="Usename">
    <input class="email"      type="email"    name="email"       placeholder="Email">
    <input class="pass"       type="password" name="pass"        placeholder="Password">
    <input class="submit"     type="submit"   name="reg"         value="Sign In">
</div>
```

where is the problem here? When I click reg button it does not show the echo, what is the problem here please. It does not work even if I add other if statements.

Comment: **The problem here is that you're hiding the useful error messages with the error suppression operator (`@`).** Remove those, `var_dump($reg);` and find out why it is not `TRUE`.

Comment: @ is a good indicator of bad code :)

Comment: i dont understand quite the point of this

Comment: Never use @ and you'll force yourself to write better (not good - just better) code. That's my point.

Answer (score 4):

You need a form to submit your data

```
<form method="POST">
 ... your form element goes here
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, You can use `isset()` function to check the `$_POST['reg']`

```
if(isset($_POST['reg'])){
  $fn   =   strip_tags($_POST['fname']);
  $ln   =   strip_tags($_POST['lname']);
  $un   =   strip_tags($_POST['uname']);
  $em   =   strip_tags($_POST['email']); 
  $pswd =   strip_tags($_POST['pass']);  
  $d = date('Y-m-d');

 echo 'test';
}
```

html:

```
<form method="POST">
  your html content
</form>
```

Comment: `isset()` is a good idea, but I'd add a `name` attribute for the form submit button, and then check if it's set to see if the form was submitted. You could optionally check `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {`, too.